# itext: Nested lists in PdfPCell are shown incomplete

Tags: java, itext

I'm using iText 2.1.7 to generate a PDF document. I have problems with nested lists. When adding a nested list to a Document it works correctly. However, if the same nested list is added to a PdfPCell, which itself is part of PdfPTable, then some items in the top list are missing. Is my code incorrect or is this is bug?

Here's a code that demonstrates the issue:

```
com.lowagie.text.List sublistEOS = new com.lowagie.text.List(com.lowagie.text.List.UNORDERED, 10);
sublistEOS.add(new ListItem("D60"));
sublistEOS.add(new ListItem("D70"));
com.lowagie.text.List sublistPowerShot = new com.lowagie.text.List(com.lowagie.text.List.UNORDERED, 10);
sublistPowerShot.add(new ListItem("G15"));
sublistPowerShot.add(new ListItem("GX"));
com.lowagie.text.List sublistC = new com.lowagie.text.List(com.lowagie.text.List.UNORDERED, 10);
sublistC.add(new ListItem("EOS"));
sublistC.add(sublistEOS);
sublistC.add(new ListItem("Powershot"));
sublistC.add(sublistPowerShot);
com.lowagie.text.List list = new  com.lowagie.text.List(com.lowagie.text.List.UNORDERED, 10);
list.add(new ListItem("Canon"));
list.add(sublistC);
list.add(new ListItem("Nikon"));

//this works well
document.add(list);

//this doesn't work well - list item Nikon is missing!
PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
cell.addElement(list);
document.add(table)
```

**UPDATE**:
The problem is that in the real code, I'm not creating the List myself, I get it as a result of calling

```
HTMLWorker.parseToList(new StringReader(html), styleSheet)
```

where html is string containing any HTML (in my case it contains nested lists)
So I can't easily influence the structure of the generated List (which looks good to me and it works nicely when added directly to the document)
I've been playing around with my example code (Canon, Nicon..) and I've found out that the problem occurs if the last item of a List is another List (not ListItem). So I've written an 'correction' recursive method that accepts a List and adds a fake ListItem if needed:

```
private void processList(com.lowagie.text.List aList) {
    ListItem fakeLI = new ListItem();
    List items = aList.getItems();
    for(int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
        Object item = items.get(i);
        if (item instanceof com.lowagie.text.List) {
            processList((com.lowagie.text.List)item);//recursive call
            if (i + 1 == items.size()) {
                items.add(fakeLI);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

so in my example code I call:

```
cell.addElement(processList(list));
```

this 'seems' to work but maybe there's a better work around out there. I incline to think that it is a bug in iText.

Comment: It *is* not a bug in iText. It *was* a bug in iText. You're using an obsolete version that was released in July 2009. The bug you're mentioning has been solved. Please do not report bugs that have been fixed! Please upgrade to the latest version of iText instead.

Comment: OK, thanks for this infomation. So it WAS a bug and it has been fixed (how am I supposed to know?). Unfortunatelly, due to licencing reasons I'm not able to move to a newer version of iText - if I'm not mistaken, 2.1.7 was still under LPGL, while 5.0 and newer is not:-( My company management refuses to pay a commercial licence so that we don't have to publish our proprietary code so I'm stuck with the old iText forever:-(

Comment: Your company management probably made a decision based on the wrong arguments. Please watch this video where one of our customers explains the benefits: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uzF8E4h7Evo We've just done a survey and customers (including customers of your company) don't want PDFs created by an obsolete version of iText. They want you to use the new version. The argument that pricing is too high is usually based on a misunderstanding. Just get in touch with iText and maybe we can help you convince your management that you should get the tools you deserve.

Answer (score 1):

### Are You Expecting this out put if else please specify the order and i will try to get it done

[image]

And I am using com.itextpdf package

```
    package test1;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.OutputStream;

    import com.itextpdf.*;
    import com.itextpdf.text.Document;
    import com.itextpdf.text.DocumentException;
    import com.itextpdf.text.List;
    import com.itextpdf.text.ListItem;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPCell;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPTable;
    import com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter;
    public class JavaIText {

        /**
         * @param args
         * @throws DocumentException 
         * @throws IOException 
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) throws DocumentException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             OutputStream file = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\PDF_Java4s.pdf"));
            Document document =new Document();
             PdfWriter.getInstance(document, file);
            com.itextpdf.text.List sublistEOS = new com.itextpdf.text.List(com.itextpdf.text.List.UNORDERED, 10);

            sublistEOS.add(new ListItem("D60"));
            sublistEOS.add(new ListItem("D70"));

            com.itextpdf.text.List sublistPowerShot = new com.itextpdf.text.List(com.itextpdf.text.List.UNORDERED, 10);

            sublistPowerShot.add(new ListItem("G15"));
            sublistPowerShot.add(new ListItem("GX"));

            com.itextpdf.text.List sublistC = new com.itextpdf.text.List(com.itextpdf.text.List.UNORDERED, 10);

            sublistC.add(new ListItem("EOS"));
            sublistC.add(sublistEOS);

            sublistC.add(new ListItem("Powershot"));
            sublistC.add(sublistPowerShot);

            com.itextpdf.text.List list = new  com.itextpdf.text.List(com.itextpdf.text.List.UNORDERED, 10);
            list.add(new ListItem("Canon"));

            list.add(sublistC);
            com.itextpdf.text.List list1 = new  com.itextpdf.text.List(com.itextpdf.text.List.UNORDERED, 10);

            list1.add(new ListItem("Nikon"));


             document.open();
            //this works well
            document.add(list);


            PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(1);
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
            cell.addElement(list);
```

For Display Nokion as second item add it as a seperate List

```
            cell.addElement(list1);
            cell.setPaddingBottom(8);

            table.addCell(cell);
            document.add(table);
            document.close();

            file.close();

        }

    }
```

### The solution to this problem is add each root List items as individual list

[image]

[image: Pdf]

Comment: Okay Is this what you want

Comment: yes, I'm expecting the output as in the screenshot. I only get it when List is added to Document directly. If List is added to a table, then 'Nikon' is not rendedered. 
I've tested the same code with iText 5.5.0 but the result is the same:-(

Comment: Hey i encountered the same problem when running your code the work around is add every sublist under cannon (List)  then create another list item List1 in this case or any other name as you wish enter it and add it to pdftable's cell i have added two cells to show that it works

Comment: @user3514427 is using an obsolete version of iText. It isn't fair to say "there's a bug in iText" when that bug has been fixed ages ago. I've upvoted the answer and I suggest that user3514427 accepts it.

Comment: Cheers i was wondering it works fine what is it that failed to notice